# asp.net mvc control-set recommendation

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, controls

Which control-set do you recommend for asp.net mvc 3 ? Can you please expose some details, pros, cons, etc... if you know. Not important if it is free or commercial.

Regards,
Serdar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At my job, my team uses the [Telerik MVC controls](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx).

Pros:

- Pretty easy to setup and use
- Good support
- Decent visuals

Cons:

- They're controls.  (If I can help it, I prefer to keep it simple)